# webdriver downloads the temp file rather than the csv?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I wrote a piece of code that looks for companies on this website https://violationtracker.goodjobsfirst.org/ and downloads the csv result of the company page - see the example for Nike here:  https://violationtracker.goodjobsfirst.org/prog.php?parent=&major_industry_sum=&offense_group_sum=&primary_offense_sum=&agency_sum=&agency_sum_st=&hq_id_sum=&company_op=starts&company=nike&major_industry%5B%5D=&case_category=&offense_group=&all_offense%5B%5D=&penalty_op=%3E&penalty=&govt_level=&agency_code%5B%5D=&agency_code_st%5B%5D=&pen_year%5B%5D=&pres_term=&free_text=&case_type=&ownership%5B%5D=&hq_id=&naics%5B%5D=&state=&city=)

The code worked for long, but now I am not sure why instead of downloading the CSV it only downloads a temp file? There is nothing wrong with the site since I tried manually and I could download the csv.

This is my code

```
df_all = []


supplier = ['Nike']

length = len(supplier)

##go to the website
for idx, i in enumerate(supplier):
    rem = length-idx
    print('This is index: ', idx, ', element: ', i, ', with remaining : ', rem, ' elements')
    try:
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe")
        driver.get("https://www.goodjobsfirst.org/violation-tracker")

    ##find the iframe with the broweser 
        driver.switch_to_frame(0)
    ## Insert text via xpath ##
        elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='edit-field-violation-company-value']")
        elem.send_keys(i)
        elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
        time.sleep(10) 
        try:
            ##download the information from the relevant page
            button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div/div[2]/a[1]/img')
            ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(button).click(button).perform()
            ##upload last csv in the download folder
            list_of_files = glob.glob(r'C:\Users\~\Downloads\*.csv')
            latest_file = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)
            time.sleep(3)
            df = pd.read_csv(latest_file)
            print(df)
            df_all.append(df)
            driver.close()
            if os.path.exists(latest_file):
                os.remove(latest_file)
            else:
                print("The file does not exist")
        except:
            driver.close()
    except:
        pass



violation_tracker = pd.concat(df_all)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

This site looks very interesting ! Thanks for that.

By just adding "&detail=csv_results" at the end of the second URL. The following code works :

```
import requests as rq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import csv

headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0"}
url = "https://violationtracker.goodjobsfirst.org/prog.php?parent=&major_industry_sum=&offense_group_sum=&primary_offense_sum=&agency_sum=&agency_sum_st=&hq_id_sum=&company_op=starts&company=nike&major_industry[]=&case_category=&offense_group=&all_offense[]=&penalty_op=%3E&penalty=&govt_level=&agency_code[]=&agency_code_st[]=&pen_year[]=&pres_term=&free_text=&case_type=&ownership[]=&hq_id=&naics[]=&state=&city=&detail=csv_results"

resp = rq.get(url, headers=headers)
a = resp.content
wrapper = csv.reader(resp.text.strip().split('\n'))
for record in wrapper:
    print(record)
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for this! The problem is that often I am looping through multiple company information, so I would need to rewrite my code to retrieve the URL each time and get the csv..not a biggie, but I was curious to figure out what could be the problem? why did it stop working while it works when I do it manually?